# wp_get_attachment_image_src returning wrong dimentions

Tags: php, wordpress

For some reason wp_get_attachment_image_src is returning wrong dimensions!  Not sure why.  The file exists and the image size is registered in setup.  Does anyone have an idea?  I am going crazy here.

Code:

```
# in setup function
add_image_size('thumb', 400, 0, false);

# in template file
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumb', false);
```

Result:

```
array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(115) "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/this-is-an-image-400x331.jpg"
    [1]=>
    int(150)
    [2]=>
    int(124)
    [3]=>
    bool(true)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the name **thumb** is Reserved Image Size.

**Reserved Image Size Names:**

- thumb
- thumbnail
- medium
- large
- post-thumbnail

See the [Docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size#Reserved_Image_Size_Names)

Answer (score 0):

Does changing the third parameter thumb to thumbnail, in the `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` function, help because the [manual](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) talks about 4 options as far as the size is concerned. (viz. thumbnail, medium, large or full).

Also consider changing the first parameter in `add_image size` because it is a reserved term / word, as mentioned in the [manual](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size).